# Api's service is limited to USA locations only

Tags: node.js, flutter, geolocation

I am making a food order and delivery app. My app is currently live on aws . Frontend is made using flutter and backend Currently I'am developing this Outside USA location using node.js. Api service I'am using is of mealme.ai . Problem with mealme.ai is that it works for USA locations. So, when a user "places order", it gives status 200 but doesn't place order. I tried using VPN service but it didn't worked.

What can be the possible approaches for this for testing ?

I tried mealme.ai api's, I don't know how to develop using aws. So, give some approaches for this !

I tried using vpn but not worked. How can I execute the testing and make api's work properly from outside US location ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.